# Simplifying logical expression

Tags: logical-operators, circuit, circuit-diagram

Is there a way to reduce this logical expression? I map out the circuit design to logical expression but I can't find a way to reduce it more, I feel that there is a way to do so. I've tried De Morgan's law but that only changes one statement not entirely reduce it.

[image: Logical Design]

[image: Logical Expression]

Comment: Have you heard of Karnaugh Maps? They are for simplifying boolean algebra which this is.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There exists software for doing this. If you enter your expression into e.g. Logic Friday, you get the following simpler result:
S0' L1  + S1' L1  + S0' L3  + S1' L3  + S0 S1' L2  + S0 S1 L4

Alternatively in POS form:
(S1+L1+L2+L3)(S0+L1+L3)(S0'+S1'+L4)